# What's the deal with the rat king?

Tags: pixel-dungeon

I've found a "rat king" monster on floor 5 in a treasure room behind a secret door. I can't seem to attack it, and it just wonders the floor aimlessly. What's the point with that monster? Is there any way to defeat it, or does it have any other gameplay impact?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taken from the [Wiki](http://pixeldungeon.wikia.com/wiki/Rat_king).

> The rat king was added as an easter egg referencing an aprils fools joke on reddit.
>
> The rat king will try to run away from you if he sees you. You cannot harm the rat in any way.

[image: Rat King]

Comment: You can however talk to it...

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if you try and attack the King Rat too many times, he starts to hit you; taking 1 HP away each hit.

Comment: This is very nearly a comment the way its worded.

Answer (score 0):

The rat king was added as an easter egg and does nothing but run around the level.

Interacting with it makes it say: "I'm not sleeping!" And Interacting with it again will make it say something else.

The rat king spawns in the rat king room which is lined with chests.
The rat king cannot be harmed by any means exept by using a scroll of wipe out.

In remixed pixel duenguoen the rat king can be killed easily

Answer (score -1):

Use scroll of wipeout.
After that the chests you open in the secret room on Goo level should give you good items such as battle axe / halberd etc.